# Replacing European dates with ISO dates in a file using Bash

Tags: bash, date

I have multiple dates one several lines of a JSON file and I would like to rewrite from EU format `DD-MM-YYYY` to ISO format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

All dates are considered to be valid, so the algorithm can be string positional only.

```
{"title":"...","frequency":"M","observations":[{"ObservationPeriod":{"periodId":1760,"periodFirstDate":"01-04-1993 00:00:00","periodName":"Avr 1993","value":null}},{"ObservationPeriod":{"periodId":1761,"periodFirstDate":"01-05-1993 00:00:00","periodName":"Mai 1993","value":null}},{"ObservationPeriod":{"periodId":1762,"periodFirstDate":"01-06-1993 00:00:00","periodName":"Jun 1993","value":null}},{"ObservationPeriod":{"periodId":1763,"periodFirstDate":"01-07-1993 00:00:00","periodName":"Jul 1993","value":null}},{"ObservationPeriod":{"periodId":1764,"periodFirstDate":"01-08-1993 00:00:00","periodName":"Aoû 1993","value":null}}]}
...
```

How can I do this using a bash one liner?

Thank you.

Comment: "US format" is MM-DD-YYYY; YYYY-MM-DD (as used in the ISO 8601 international standard) is far too well-designed to be a US thing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed` and this observation,

```sh
echo "01-12-2018, 18-12-2020" | sed 's/\([0-9]\{2\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)-\([0-9]\{4\}\)/\3-\2-\1/g'
# 2018-12-01, 2020-12-18
```

To replace the file in place just use,

```sh
sed -i '' 's/\([0-9]\{2\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)-\([0-9]\{4\}\)/\3-\2-\1/g' your_file.json
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using `sed`

```
echo '{"title":"Crédits à l'habitat  accordés aux particuliers résidents, taux de croissance annuel","titleCompl":"Crédits à l'habitat (y compris crédits titrisés) accordés aux particuliers résidents  par les établissements de crédit et assimilés résidents, toutes devises, taux de croissance annuel","frequency":"M","observations":[{"ObservationPeriod":{"periodId":1760,"periodFirstDate":"01-04-1993 00:00:00","periodName":"Avr 1993","value":null}},{"ObservationPeriod":{"periodId":1761,"periodFirstDate":"01-05-1993 00:00:00","periodName":"Mai 1993","value":null}},{"ObservationPeriod":{"periodId":1762,"periodFirstDate":"01-06-1993 00:00:00","periodName":"Jun 1993","value":null}},{"ObservationPeriod":{"periodId":1763,"periodFirstDate":"01-07-1993 00:00:00","periodName":"Jul 1993","value":null}},{"ObservationPeriod":{"periodId":1764,"periodFirstDate":"01-08-1993 00:00:00","periodName":"Aoû 1993","value":null}}]}' | sed --regexp-extended 's/\"([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})\s/\"\3-\2-\1 /g'
```

Output will be:

```
{"title":"Crédits à lhabitat accordés aux particuliers résidents, taux de croissance annuel,titleCompl:Crédits à lhabitat (y compris crédits titrisés) accordés aux particuliers résidents  par les établissements de crédit et assimilés résidents, toutes devises, taux de croissance annuel","frequency":"M","observations":[{"ObservationPeriod":{"periodId":1760,"periodFirstDate":"1993-04-01 00:00:00","periodName":"Avr 1993","value":null}},{"ObservationPeriod":{"periodId":1761,"periodFirstDate":"1993-05-01 00:00:00","periodName":"Mai 1993","value":null}},{"ObservationPeriod":{"periodId":1762,"periodFirstDate":"1993-06-01 00:00:00","periodName":"Jun 1993","value":null}},{"ObservationPeriod":{"periodId":1763,"periodFirstDate":"1993-07-01 00:00:00","periodName":"Jul 1993","value":null}},{"ObservationPeriod":{"periodId":1764,"periodFirstDate":"1993-08-01 00:00:00","periodName":"Aoû 1993","value":null}}]}
```